# Use function on a number only once

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a question - is it possible to make function only work once on a number, to avoid duplicate?
If an array has `{1,2,2}`

i'd like the `void(n)` to use 2 only once

do I need to remove duplicates from an array with some function, or is there any other method?

Comment: The modus-operandi for doing this is going to be directly related to the *specific* nature of your code that requires it. How the numbers are stored, how the numbers are iterated, whether things like a functor, a static, or some other potential implementation is appropriate. The answer is yes, you can do it. How depends entirely on what ingredients you're cooking with and how the kitchen is laid out. Certainly building a no-duplicate copy and iterating that will work. If its appropriate to your scenario, do it.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it that you really want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you need to have some kind of duplicate removal steps. Better to use `unordered_set` if an order doesn't matter otherwise use `set`.

Comment: Assuming `arr` is an array of `int` with `n_arr` elements and all duplicate values are consecutive (e.g. `{1,2,2}` or `{2,2,1}` is okay but `{2,1,2}` is not)   then  `std::for_each(arr, std::unique(arr, arr + n_arr), your_func)` will do it.    If duplicate values are not consecutive,  sort `arr` first.

Answer (score 1):

Convert array into set. This will avoid duplicates.

```
arr= [1,2,2]
std::unordered_set<int> s;
    for (int i: arr) {
        s.insert(i);
    }
```

Comment: I need to use C++ 98 version, sets are from c++ 11

Comment: @debooger3 having such a hard and unusual constraint is something you have to mention in the question. Otherwise you waste the time of the people that write and answer.